# When to use em dashes in place of commas

Tags: grammar, commas, dashes

To minimize transmission—which mainly occurs through the inhalation of infected droplets, many countries have enacted nationwide lockdowns, closing all but ‘essential’ businesses and putting most regular activities on hold.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why is this marked grammar? It's still just the same words in the same order, so grammar is immaterial.

Comment: Use em dashes to set off a phrase.

Comment: Nope, not correct.  Please review info on the web regarding "parenthetical phrase".

Answer (score 1):

Not correct. Stay consistent with comma or em dash with your sample sentence:
1) "To minimize transmission, which mainly..."
2) "...of infected droplets--many countries..."